# Cannot get jQuery UI to enqueue in my plugin!

Tags: plugin-development

Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but I could use some help.

My plugin architecture is below...

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'my_post_options_box');
add_action('admin_menu', 'my_post_options_box');

//enqueue jquery ui here
function my_load_js() {
    echo "called"; //THIS ECHO FIRES
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-core');
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery-ui-widget');
    }

function my_post_options_box() {
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_load_js' );//DOES NOT LOAD THE .JS
    $my_dir = plugins_url('/img', __FILE__);
    add_options_page( '...my options page settings here');
    register_setting( 'my_settings_options', 'my_settings', 'my_settings_validate' );
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong but when I view the source of the page in which the plugin is loaded, there is no .js file loaded for the jquery ui files I'm trying to enqueue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hook `my_load_js()` to [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Examples) as in the examples in the Codex, and not to `admin_init`.

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_js');
```

...pretty sure that will take care of it.